# S60 emulator hide virtual keyboard

Tags: java-me, touch, screen, emulation

I'm looking for J2ME emulator for touch screen 360 X 640.
Can anyone help me with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have using

```
Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no
```

in the JAD file and it solved the problem.